# Proving convergence by convergence of 3 subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm studying for my real analysis exam and came across this prompt:

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers. If the subsequences $\{a_{2k}\}$,
$\{a_{2k+1}\}$and $\{a_{3k}\}$ converge, prove that $\{a_n\}$  converges.

I thought maybe that I could prove $\{a_n\}$ converges by first showing it's a Cauchy sequence, but I have not made much progress.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could show me an easy way to do this proof or even just give an outline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**: what can you say about $(a_{2k})$ and $(a_{2k+1})$ limits if $(a_{3k})$ converges?

Let $\lim (a_{2k})=L$,  $\lim (a_{2k+1})=L'$,  $\lim (a_{3k})=L''$.

Extract $(a_{6k})$,  from $(a_{2k})$ with $k\mapsto 3k$. You then have $\lim (a_{6k})=\lim (a_{2k})=L$. Using $k \mapsto 2k$, $\lim (a_{6k})= \lim (a_{3k})=L''$. As limit is unique, $L=L''$.

Then extract $(a_{6k+3})$,  from $(a_{2k+1})$ with $k\mapsto 3k+1$. You then have $\lim (a_{6k+3})=\lim (a_{2k+1})=L'$. Using $k \mapsto 2k+1$, $\lim (a_{6k+3})= \lim (a_{3k})=L''$. As limit is unique, $L'=L''$.

Hence :
$$\lim (a_{3k})= \lim (a_{2k})= \lim (a_{2k+1})=L.$$

Now use the definition of $\lim(u_n)=L$ for $(a_{2n})$ and $(a_{2n+1})$.

Comment: Is there an easy conclusion after I write down the \epsilon-N definition of lim?

Comment: Yes. What happens if you take the maximum of the two indexes?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints:

- Lets say that $\lim_{k \to \infty} a_{2k} = a_{even} \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{k \to \infty} a_{2k+1} = a_{odd} \in \mathbb{R}$. Under what condition does $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ exist?
- What can you say about the subsequences $(a_{6k})$ and $(a_{6k + 3})$ of $(a_{3k})$?

If you really want the complete proof, just leave a comment :)

Comment: Ok, so I get that the limits are the same, but I don't see where the importance of the 3rd subsequence $(a_{3k})$ comes in and necessarily makes $(a_n)$ converge.

Comment: You can't prove that the limits are the same without $(a_{3k)$. That's why you need it.

Comment: Could I see an argument for why the limits must be the same?

Comment: You can find common extracted sequence from $(a_{3k})$ and $(a_{2k})$, and $(a_{3k})$ and $(a_{2k+1})$. Then use limit uniqueness and the fact that 'mother' and 'children' sequence have the same limit.

Comment: Ok great! Now I'm not sure where I should go from here

Comment: Updated my post.